# Acumatica Custom Dataprovider to import data via API

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to find the best option in Acumatica to import data from another system. The requirments are as follows:

1. The third party system will provide us the endpoints and authentication details
2. We have to use Acumatica to import data from the third party using the API provided and create Purchase orders in Acumatica.
3. A regular import on this data will need to be set up

I'm a new Acumatica developer, and my initial instinct was to create a custom data provider like sales force and hubspot providers. I know there are examples of custom data providers to import data from csv and excel files but I couldn't find one where it connects to a third-party API.

If data provider is not the answer, do I have to create a separate RestAPI project to PULL data from the third party. In that case, can someone help me on how to schedule it. I was thinking maybe call the GET method using a timestamp to avoid pulling all payments from the other system.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Is this integration meant to be published on different acumatica instances or is this particular customer implementation?

Comment: It's for a customer implementation.

Comment: Did you go with custom processing screen or custom data provider? I have a similar scenario but I have a lot of external systems to pull API data from. Would like to get your feedback on what issues you experienced and the time it took you to complete this.

Comment: @RuaanVolschenk Unfortunately I left my job before it was approved. Didn't get a chance to work on this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop a **custom processing screen** to import the data:

https://www.acumatica.com/blog/creating-custom-processing-screens-in-acumatica/

Processing screen automatically provide a built-in scheduler that run the process at scheduled interval:
[image]

When building a custom processing screen you must follow guidelines of 'Processing Screen' but there are no restriction on how to develop the import logic. You don't need a custom data provider if you built a custom processing screen for import logic.

AUSchedule DAC to determine the date/time of the last scheduled execution:

```
PXGraph graph = this; // or Base or any graph instance

foreach (PX.SM.AUSchedule schedule in 
    PXSelect<PX.SM.AUSchedule,
        Where<PX.SM.AUSchedule.screenID, Equal<Required<PX.SM.AUSchedule.screenID>>>>
           .Select(graph, PXSiteMap.CurrentScreenID))
{
    // Check LastRunResult and LastRunStatus fields for last run success/completed
    DateTime? lastExecution = schedule.LastRunDate;
}
```

Instead of looking up last schedule execution you can create a setup DAC in which you have the API configuration URL/credential and put a last run custom field there. When process is run you can update that custom last run field to save the last synchronization time accurately.

---

You can also build a **custom data provider** and use it with a custom **import scenario**. A custom data provider is required only for 'import scenario' which is the built-in method of importing data in Acumatica. Import Scenario are more complex than building a processing screen. In both case you will need to do some programming/configuration to perform REST API call to get data from external service.

You can learn more about building a custom data provider here:
https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/09/custom-integration-services-data.html

You can get more information about import scenarios in Acumatica training documents:
https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/reporting/i100-integration-scenarios/

Comment: Thank you very much Hugues for the information. With the given time, I think the best solution would be the custom processing form to do the import where I have the freedom to develop the import logic easily. In my free time, I would do the custom data provider as a new project.

Comment: I added a sample BQL query to show how to get the last date of scheduled run of the process. This can be used for your timestamp requirements. I suggest you create a setup DAC in which you have the API configuration URL/credential and put a last run custom field there. When process is run you can update that custom last run field to save the last synchronization time accurately.

Comment: Thank you again. I'll go with the setup DAC solution.